# Scipy callback is called only once

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback, scipy, minimize

I am using [tf scipy interface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface), to use scipy `minimize` over a custom function that I define in tensorflow. I need to debug it and I want to use a callback function to print some info.
However, the callback function is called only once, despite the number of iterations / function evaluations / gradient evaluations are more than one. Why? I am getting the same problem using just scipy (without tensorflow).

Here is a MWE with the Rosenbrock function (it should say that the minimizer does 23 iterations, 53 function evaluation, 23 gradient evaluations, but `CALLBACK!` is printed only twice, once for `step_callback` and once for `loss_callback`).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Solver:
    def __init__(self, session, y, x):
        self.session = session
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(self.y,
                                              options={'maxiter': 100, 'disp': True},
                                              method='SLSQP',
                                              var_list=[self.x],
                                              var_to_bounds={self.x: (1e-8, np.infty)})

    def optimize(self):
      self.optimizer.minimize(self.session, step_callback=self.callback(), loss_callback=self.callback())

    def callback(self):
        print('CALLBACK!')


def main():
    seed = 0
    np.random.seed(seed)
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    session = tf.Session()

    x_size = 10
    x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(x_size), dtype=tf.float32)
    y = 0.
    for i in range(x_size-1):
        y += 100. * (x[i+1] - x[i]*x[i])**2 + (x[i] - 1)**2

    solver = Solver(session, y, x)

    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    solver.optimize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You are not passing a function (as expected both in scipy and this wrapper according to the docs). You are passing an evaluation of a function. I never used tf or this wrapper, so no code. Remove the ```()``` to pass a function. E.g. ```step_callback=self.callback```.

Comment: Omg, it was such a stupid mistake. Thanks! (I am pretty new to python and tf). If you write it as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding to my comment above)

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface):

> step_callback: A function to be called at each optimization step; arguments are the current values of all optimization variables flattened into a single vector.
>
> loss_callback: A function to be called every time the loss and gradients are computed, with evaluated fetches supplied as positional arguments.

you have to pass a function.

A simple example showing the problem in your case, where you are **not passing a function; but an evaluation of a function** would be the following.

Keep in mind, that i will only show some pure scipy-example and instead of the -argument `self`, i'm passing an vector (which is the usual case in callbacks). It looks different, but it transfers to your case!

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen

def callback(xs):
    print('callback')

x0 = np.zeros(5)

print('Wrong passing')
res = minimize(rosen, np.zeros(5), callback=callback(x0))  # need some arg x0 to make it run
                                                           # in your case this is "self"
print('Correct passing')
res = minimize(rosen, np.zeros(5), callback=callback)
```

Out:

```
Wrong passing
callback
alpha1:  1.0
Correct passing
callback
callback
callback
callback
...
...
alpha1:  1.0
```

In your case you could also do one more debugging-experiment which shows the problem. Introduce two different callbacks, one for `step_callback` and one for `loss_callback`. You will see that **each is called exactly once** (single time of evaluation before actually starting optimization!).